# "Error: EMFILE: too many open files" using Xcode to archive React Native App

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I know there are a lot of similar questions out there, but my issue seems to be unique, and the solutions suggested aren't solving it:

I'm trying to build an archive of a React Native App from Xcode and, since updating to macOS 11.3.1 and Xcode 12.5, I get `"Error: EMFILE: too many open files"` when Xcode is trying to run the `node bundle` command.

I've already installed and updated watchman via homebrew, and have also increased my system's maximum open files and open files per process to unreasonably high values.

Oddly enough, I *can* do a *debug* build from Xcode with no issues, and running the `node bundle` command that Xcode's archive fails on from the command line completes without any issues. I'm able to run and debug the App with no issues, it's just when Xcode is trying to bundle the js for an archive that it seems to fail.

It's almost like Xcode is not using watchman (while the terminal is) and/or it's process has a limit on the number of open files that is different from what I get in the terminal.

Comment: facing same issue in mac m1. have you found any fix?

Comment: I'm afraid I have not 

Comment: having the very exact same problem on m1, installed watchman, debug build works, running bundle manually works too, but from xcode doesnt work, and runs and installs fine on debug builds. increased ulimit as well

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here's how I fixed it.

I believe this error is happening due to the bundle for iOS is missing so it's trying to build the bundle when Xcode is building the app (it shouldnt fail but no idea why it does)

I fixed it by first adding this command to my package.json to build the iOS bundle manually.

`"bundle:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'",`

I ran `npm run bundle:ios` first, and then I proceeded to add the bundle file in Xcode,
under `Build Phases` => `Copy Bundle Resources`

[image: Copy Bundle Resources Step after adding the jsbundle]

I cleaned my project in Xcode and the build works after.